Cant see Angular16 Application in NW.js window
Trying to get my angular app running in NW.js but having some issues.
On a fresh project using the latest angular version 16, and correct versions of node and npm installed. Using npm i can install the nw package, and configure my package.json like this:
{
  "name": "nw-test-proj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "nwstart": "nw ."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "nw": "^0.87.0-sdk",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}


But when i run my app with this index.html body:
<body>
<p>hello</p>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>

A window will pop up but i can only see the p-tag and "hello" in the window, and nothing inside my app-root
Ive spent a few days looking online for any resources and double checking documentation but cant find anything. Ive followed a few guide for Angular and NW.js and how to setup, and its all very basic and easy to start up an app in an NW.js window, but for some reason my src files arent loaded by the window and/or i cant see my actual application beyond app-root.
Ive tried using the source files, both sdk and normal but those dont work either.

This boilerplate is for Angular 17 and NW.js:

https://github.com/nwutils/nw-angular-example

You should start there and move your files over.

Ive cloned this example and tried running it but the same thing happens, when i edit the nw-angular-example's entry point to index.html file, a window will pop up but nothing inside the app-root shows

On a fresh clone of that repo, doing npm install && npm start, does it work? If so, then the issue lies in your code and what you are doing. If it doesn't work, then you have an issue with your dev environment. Perhaps a mismatch in your Node version (should be 21.1.0 per the volta object). If I add <p>TEST</p> above <app-root></app-root> in the src/index.html and save, then refresh the app, it shows the text on the screen.
